# Blueimp S3 Thumbnails Don’t Display

Tags: json, laravel, amazon-s3, blueimp, laravel-5.7

I'm using Blueimp with S3 in my Laravel 5.7 project, the upload worked perfectly but it's not showing the thumbnail after upload. I'm using a temporary URL to view the files, but only the thumbnail is not working. Has anyone had a similar problem?

**Upload return JSON for Blueimp**

```
$photographSave = $album->photograph()->create($data);
```

> photographSave = Model Photograph, $photographSave->photograph = url file

```
return [
    'files' => [
        [
            'deleteType' => '',
            'deleteUrl' => '',
            'name' => $name,
            'size' => \Storage::disk('local')->size($path . $name),
            'type' => 'image/' . $request->file('files')[0]->getClientOriginalExtension(),
            'thumbnailUrl' => UploadFile::getThumbS3($photographSave->photograph),
            'url' => UploadFile::getFile($photographSave->photograph),
        ],
    ]
];
```

**Generate URL function**

```
protected static function getThumbS3($file)
{
    try {
        return
            Storage::disk('s3')->temporaryUrl(
                $file, Carbon::now()->addMinutes(5)
            );
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```